# What happens when you push a memory address in assembly?

Tags: assembly, push, memory-address, disassembly

I am trying to reverse engineer a disassembled binary. I don't understand what it is doing when it makes a call such as:

push $0x804a254

What makes it even more confusing is that that address is not and address of an instruction nor is it in the symbol table. What is it doing?

Comment: It's pushing some sort of 32-bit number onto the stack.  Without some sort of context, it's completely impossible to say anything further.

Comment: Yes, post a piece of the disassembly, not a single instruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of 3 cases: its either a constant(be it a hash, number, bitflags or a typecasted address), the address of a variable or buffer(this includes string literals) that is statically allocated at any scope or a missanalyzed operand(due to encryption/junking). Its true meaning is relative to its use(be it a call argument or and indirect method of setting a mem/reg).

Answer (score 1):

The value you see there is not in any table nor an instruction because it is a local variable. (Local variables to not maintain any name associated with a symbol table since they are only "alive" while you are in a specific method) The address is equivalent to something like

```
void somefunc()
{
  int t; //t may have address 0x804a254 since this is a local variable.
}
```

In order to properly free memory local variable are allocated on the system stack instead of somewhere else in memory. they are pushed when the function is created and popped off when the function returns, thats what you are seeing.

Comment: Aren't local function variables referenced using esp (or ebp) register instead on x86? I think that 0x804a254 could be rather a global variable address or a constant that is later popped out...

Comment: Local variables are addressed relative to the stack pointer (e.g. ebp or esp), not by absolute address. So I doubt that's what's happening here.

Comment: So is it a global variable because they didn't just push 0x4 or %eax or something? If so, it wouldn't make sense to make it global if it is never reference again. 
Also, what does 
jmp    *0x804b0fc
mean when that address also isn't referenced anywhere else in the disassembly or symbol table?

Comment: That is entirely system dependent, however, another possibility could be that as some systems do, the raw value of a DWORD pushed onto the stack directly which if the value was a pointer itself could be resulting value, However w/o knowing what Compiler/Language/Platform its hard to tell, they all have different implementations

Comment: Only static local function variables can be referenced by constant address. I can't come up with any other case unless one has really smart compiler that can precalculate that particular function will always be located in the same stack address.

Answer (score 1):

That instruction simply pushes 32-bit constant (0x804a254) in the stack.

That instruction alone is not enough for us to tell how it is later used. Could you provide more dissasembly of the code? Especially I would like to see where this value is popped out, and how this value is later being used.

Before starting any reverse engineering I would recommend reading this book ([Reverse Engineering secrets](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764574817)) and then X86 instruction set manual ([Intel](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/) or [AMD](http://support.amd.com/us/Processor_TechDocs/24594.pdf)). I am assuming that you are Reverse Engineering for x86 CPU.